# iPhone audio and AFSK

Tags: iphone, audio, modem

Here is a question for all you iPhone experts:

If you guys remember the sounds that modems used to make, or when one was trying to load a program from a cassette tape – I am trying to replicate this in an iPhone for a ham radio application. I have a stream of data (ASCII) and I need to encode it as AFSK at 1200 baud. So basically everything in the stream is converted to a series of 1200 and 2200 Hz tones. It needs to sound something like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/AFSK_1200_baud.ogg

I successfully built a bit array out of the string, but when I try to assign tones to each bit I get gaps in the sound, therefore it doesn’t demodulate correctly.

Any thought of how one should tackle this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [mobilesynth](http://code.google.com/p/mobilesynth/) project is open-source. You might be able to scan that for code that generates the tones you need.

Answer (score 0):

How are you assigning tones to the bits?  Remember, a digital audio signal is just a stream of samples with values between -1 and 1.  Perhaps there is a clipping issue between tone assignments.  This can happen if the signal dives below -1 or above 1.  If it stays above or below this range at a constant value, there will be no sound.  Maybe you could output your stream of samples to check if this is the case.  Or plug the output into an oscilloscope...

Also note that clicking can occur between "uneven" transitions of signals.  For example if i output a sample with value 1 followed immediately by a sample with value -1, a click or pop will be produced.

Comment: Funny... that last part is a question on the amateur radio Extra License Class Exam.  In order to reduce key clicks, one can use a sawtooth waveform.